# How Favorite feature functions?

Tags: android, favorites

I would like to know how favorite feature functions. For example, in dictionary app if any word marked as favorite it is displayed in Favorite section. So "marking favorite" action, does it take any space on server or it is handled locally in application itself ?

To a handle it locally do I need to provide "Sign Up" functionality so that this can be done through user profile?

I working on this requirement and haven't done much of that sort so needed expert guidance on this. If anyone could please guide on this will be really a great help. I tried searching in forum already but didn't much useful threads hence posting here.

Thanks again.

Regards,

Tanuj.